# GEF editor and Tabbed Property View

Tags: java, eclipse-gef

I'm working on an editor based on **GEF** (Graphical Editing Framework) and using the Eclipse property view. My problem is that when I change a property in this view, the editor is not aware of this change and does not suggest me to save.
How can I fix this?

Comment: can you edit the file manually using some other editor ? check the permission to see if you can edit the file and save it using another editor. It might be a permission issue.

Comment: Actually when I edit a property in the properties view, my model is aware of the change. For example, the name of a component could be edited but the editor does not suggest me to save.

Comment: Are you actually coding the editor ? 

Does the editor allow you to save when the changes are not from the property view ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you perform edits outside the editor's command stack. Actually, the dirty flag (the save suggestion you refer to) is controlled by the `org.eclipse.gef.commands.CommandStack` bound to it's own GEF graphical editor.

Supposing you are implementing a property sheet editor by extending an `AdvancedPropertySection`, you have to get the `CommandStack` adapter from the `IWorkbenchPart` and save it for later use:

```
public class GEFAdvancedPropertySection extends AdvancedPropertySection {
    public void setInput(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        CommandStack commandStack = (CommandStack) part.getAdapter(CommandStack.class);
        if (cs != null)
            page.setRootEntry(new GEFPropertySheetEntry(commandStack));
        super.setInput(part, selection);
    }
}
```

In your `PropertySheetEntry` implementation (actually the `GEFPropertySheetEntry` in the above example) you have to execute model changes by means of `org.eclipse.gef.commands.Command` being executed on the saved `CommandStack`:

```
public class GEFPropertySheetEntry extends PropertySheetEntry {

    protected CommandStack commandStack;

    public GEFPropertySheetEntry(CommandStack commandStack) {
        this.commandStack = commandStack;
    }

    protected void valueChanged(PropertySheetEntry entry) {
        GEFCommand command = new GEFCommand();

        // here you have to configure the command
        // such that it can perform
        // the expected model modifications

        commandStack.execute(command);
    }
}
```

The trick is done using a specific `GEFCommand` that performs model modifications through the `CommandStack`, which is bound to the original editor and marks it as dirt.